# How should I configure my Mongodb cluster?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am running a sharded mongodb environment - 3 mongod shards, 1 mongod config, 1 mongos (no replication).

I want to use mongoimport to import csv data into the database.  I have 105million records stored in increments of 500,000 across 210 csv files.  I understand that mongoimport is single threaded and I read that I should run multiple mongoimport processes to get better performance.  However, I tried that and didn't get a speed up:

when running 3 mongoimports in parallel, I was getting ~6k inserts/sec per process (so 18k i/s) vs. running 1 mongoimport, I was getting ~20k inserts/sec.

Since these processes were routed through the single mongod config and mongos, I am wondering if this is due to my cluster configuration.  My question is, if I set up my cluster configuration differently, will I achieve better mongoimport speeds?  Do I want more mongos processes?  How many mongoimports processes should I fire off at a time?

Comment: currently testing 210 mongoimport processes.  it seems on par with 1 process...

Comment: it took right around the same time.  although it crashed my terminal, so i don't know exactly how long =P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, the first thing you need to do is "pre-split" your chunks.

Let's assume that you have already sharded the collection to which you're importing. When you start "from scratch", all of the data will start going to a single node. As that node fills up, MongoDB will start "splitting" that node into chunks. Once it gets to around 8 chunks (that's about 8x64MB of index space), it will start migrating chunks.

So basically, you're effectively writing to a single node and then that node is being slowed down because it has to read and write its data to the other nodes.

This is why you're not seeing any speedup with 3 `mongoimport`. All of the data is still going to a single node and you're maxing out that node's throughput.

The trick here is to "pre-split" the data. In your case, you would probably set it up so that you get about 70 files worth of data on each machine. Then you can import those files on different threads and get better throughput.

Jeremy Zawodny of Craigslist has a reasonable write-up on this [here](http://blog.zawodny.com/2011/03/06/mongodb-pre-splitting-for-faster-data-loading-and-importing/). The MongoDB site has some docs [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Splitting+Chunks).

Comment: The table doesn't exist before the mongoimport. how can I presplit the data before creating the table, since mongodb doesn't have any information about the table yet? 

correct me if i'm wrong, but the steps to presplit are:
1. setup 3 mongod --sharsvrs, 1 mongod --config, 3 mongos each pointing at mongod --config
2. enable sharding on the db
3. manually define where the chunk splits should occur (200mb/docsize)
4. call mongoimport on each mongos process.  

i should note that i'm splitting by uid, but the input files are not split by uid

Comment: Step 3 is correct (chunk sizes in 1.8 are 64MB). You don't need to be exactly 64MB, you just want to distribute "approximately even". Step 4 is basically correct. If you have 3 shards, I would split the files into three sets and run 3 processes. If your files do not contain sequential UIDs, then you'll have to do some work to figure out the range of keys in advance. Do you have the originals in a DB? Can you query them sorted? Can you run through the files and get an idea from those?

Comment: Great, thank you.  They're not sorted, but I know what I need to do now!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I've found a few things help with bulk loads.

Defer building indexes (except for the one you have to on the shard key) until after you've loaded everything.

Run one mongos and mongoimport per shard and load in parallel.

And the biggest improvement: Presplit your chunks.  This is a bit tricky since you need to figure out how many chunks you will need and roughly how the data is distributed.   After you split them, you have to wait for the distributor to move them all around.